# How do I create an array of multiple linked lists in c?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a linked of structures, and I need to store multiple in a fixed size array. 
Each linked list still needs to be able to be dynamically changed. I want to just 
create an array of pointers, in which the pointers point to the heads of each linked list. But I am not sure if this would work.

Comment: Try it. Show us some code and we will help you.

Comment: Put the entire linked list struct in the array. So each element of the array is a linked list struct.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Do you have any reasons you are thinking of?

Comment: What happens if the head changes. I also have only created one linked list. How do I create multiple?

Comment: What do you mean "head changes"? Are you going to swap any nodes or add elements to the head? If yes, that's right, you can't store just heads. Otherwise you can. If you are going to alter the head pointer, you should consider some wrapper struct for your lists that will contain the current head pointer, and then store the pointers to these structs in the array. Or you can update the array each time head changing.

Comment: Yes, in the program the user will be adding new structures into the list, and so the start of the list could change if a structure has a lower index then the previous head. How can I update the head in the array is my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your list node definition looks something like

```
struct node {
  T data; // for some arbitrary type T
  struct node *next;
};
```

and assuming you're using individual lists as

```
struct node *aList = createList();
addToList( &aList, newData );  // assumes the list head may change
struct node *n = findInList( aList, dataItem );
```

then all you'd need to do is something like

```
struct node *listArray[N];  // holds pointers to N separate lists
...
listArray[i] = createList();
addToList( &listArray[i], newData );
struct node *n = findInList( listArray[i], dataItem );
```

Each `listArray[i]` is a separate list; just treat it as you would any other object of type `struct node *`.

Comment: Can you expand?I am still struggling. I need help creating individual lists. Currently I have an add node function, and a delete node function.